# ignite NoSuchMethodError

Tags: apache-spark, ignite

I am using spark 3.0.0 preview and Ignite 2.7.6 with jdk 11.0 of jre 1.7 and trying to integrate ignite spark but getting below error at run-time. Each call to ignite functions  failing with same error..any-help is greatly appreciated . I am using local ignite server and default config

```
JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sc);
JavaIgniteContext igniteContext1 
=new JavaIgniteContext(jsc, new 
IgniteConfigProvider());
return ignite.configuration();

Exception in thread "main" 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError 
org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.<init>(Lorg/apache/spark/SparkContext;)
    at org.apache.ignite.spark.IgniteContext.<init>(IgniteContext.scala:113)
    at org.apache.ignite.spark.JavaIgniteContext.<init>(JavaIgnit`enter code here`eContext.scala:43)
    at org.apache.ignite.spark.JavaIgniteContext.<init>(JavaIgniteContext.scala:46)
    at utils.MemberCoverageFullLocal.main(MemberCoverageFullLocal.java:200)
```

Comment: goal is to get below code run

Comment: p1r2PFRuleDS.write() 
         .format(IgniteDataFrameSettings.FORMAT_IGNITE()) 
                    .option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_CONFIG_FILE(), CONFIG) 
                    .option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_TABLE(), "P1R2PFRule") 
                    .option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_CREATE_TABLE_PRIMARY_KEY_FIELDS(), "PERSON_ID3,Coverage_Month3,eligibility_id12") 
                 option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_CREATE_TABLE_PARAMETERS(), "template=replicated") 
   .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite); 
 //igniteSession.catalog().listColumns("P1R2PFRule").show();

Answer (score 1):

Apache Ignite 2.7.6 supports integration with Apache Spark 2.3. In the version 2.8 was also added support for Apache Spark 2.4.

Probably support for Apache Spark 3.0.0 will be added in next version.

Comment: The issue was resolved when used Ignite 2.8 with spark 2.3